# Move sDom generated html components out of datatables?

Tags: jquery, concurrency, datatables

I try to move my "sDom generated", html, search component out of my datatable using jQuery like this e.g:

```
$("#-filter_form").prepend($("#finder"));
```

I tried to put this code right after my datatable initialization method. And also some way down in my script. No luck.

When I use firebug afterwards I can do this manipulation.

I am inside document.ready() so that will not help me any more. How can I do this? Should I do some fancy concurrency programming or is there another way?

I read about this topic in datatables forum but there was nothing useful, people say that you should do it with jQuery afterwards like I tried.

[From datatables forum:](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/37/the-sdom-parameter/p1)

> allanallan August 2012 Posts: 16,405
>
> sDom can only control generated
>   elements which are within the DataTables container. However, what you
>   can do is simply move the generated elements from there generated
>   position to somewhere else in the DOM after the initialisation is
>   complete with standard jQuery / DOM methods (i.e. append /
>   appendChild).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea editing the source code.

What you should use is the function `fnDrawCallback`, that is called each time the table redraws itself. Here you can see what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      $("#upperZone").prepend($('#example_filter'));
    }});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/616/

UPDATE:

If you want to use it only once after the initialization then your function is  `fnInitComplete`.
http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/617/

Comment: Thanks for the info about fnDrawCallback, the problem is just that this method would then be called several times. Performing the DOM manipulation every time the table redraw would do some overhead function calls then? I just want this to happen once after the initialization.

Comment: Ok, I've update the answer, so you just need to replace the method name. You have also available the function fnHeaderCallback that's executed only during the header redraw.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by editing the source code.

Added a callback method to be called after all the DOM initialization.

thanks for voting me down...